# Want to convert String data type into Date data type in pentaho

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a string which has a date in this format: `n_date=2014-04-20`

I want to convert it into date data type

```
var Final_date = str2date(n_date,"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

but I get an error.

I'm do this in `pentaho`

Comment: Please post your error.

Comment: Pentaho is in Java so I have to ask - Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Could not apply the given format yyyy-MM-dd on the string for test value : Format.parseObject(String) failed (script#18)

Comment: –  jdphenix Javascript

Comment: I got this n_date string from previous database input step in pentaho.I want to convert it into date with its actual format then i store it into Postgres db.

Comment: A simple `var Final_date = new Date("2015-12-12") do not suits to you needs?

Comment: No,Bcz when i use new Date() it does not gave me an error. but when i check my date format in postgress it is wrong.

Comment: is your question about Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle)? In which step you try to convert `String` to `Date`? Is it `Modified JavaScript Value` step?

Comment: Yes it is in Pentaho Data Integration and Modified JavaScript Value step.
actully i get the date from previous step

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a Java script step to do that. It's much easier and faster to use a calculator step or a select values step instead:

1) Calculator step: Create a new field, Final_date as a Copy of field A; on Field A put the name of your input string; Data type is date and on Conversion mask choose the yyyy-MM-dd format (you don't have to pick one from the dropdown menu, you can write your own);

2) Select values: on the Metadata panel, choose your input field and Date as the data type; as above, fill in the date format your data comes in.

The difference between 1) and 2) is that in the 1st case you get a new field of the Date type, whereas in the 2nd case you change the data type of the input field.

Comment: Thanks nsousa.I will try with this step.

Comment: I have table which contain String fields,I want to convert them into numbers. but my final output is wrong after apply the function. 
  
var n_avg_cpc=parseFloat(trim(avg_cpc));
 if(avg_cpc> 0) {
 var n_avg_cpc=parseFloat(trim(avg_cpc))/1000000;
}

Comment: that should be a separate question, not a comment in this one.

Comment: I know its a comment. 
reason for ask this things is here 
when i add this text in a ask question window. i was failed.
despite all of my tries it give me error.